# Sematics of ARROW marker parameters changed between fuerte and hydro?

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-hydro, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am currently porting some code from fuerte to hydro and came across a problem that I do not fully understand.

In fuerte I used the arrow marker, and there the length of the arrow is encoded as scale.z. On hydro, scale.z seems to scale  the arrow in all dimensions.

The ROS wiki [see here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Arrow_.28ARROW.3D0.29) says:

> "scale.x is the arrow width, scale.y is the arrow height and scale.z is the arrow length ".

However, if I set scale.x and scale.y to the same value (0.1), I get an upward-oval shaped arrow, which is twice as high as wide!?!?

Does anyone have some insight on this?

Best

Georg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166961/sematics-of-arrow-marker-parameters-changed-between-fuerte-and-hydro?/) by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2014-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this has changed and we also experienced the strange oval arrows when updating from fuerte. You´ll probably want to just update your code accordingly (should be straightforward in most cases).

/edit: Just looked up what we did:

```
   // add a movable arrow to the interactive marker
   visualization_msgs::Marker arrow;
   arrow.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW;
-  arrow.scale.z = 0.5;
+  arrow.scale.x = 0.5;
+  arrow.scale.y = 0.1;
+  arrow.scale.z = 0.1;
+
   arrow.color.r = 0.5;
   arrow.color.g = 0;
@@ -940,7 +943,7 @@
   } else {
     start_marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW;
-    start_marker.scale.x = 0.2;
-    start_marker.scale.y = 0.2;
-    start_marker.scale.z = 0.8;
+    start_marker.scale.x = 0.5;
+    start_marker.scale.y = 0.1;
+    start_marker.scale.z = 0.1;
   }
```

Looks like the wiki documentation you linked is wrong (at least for current ROS versions) and y and z are scaling the height/width, while x scales the length of the marker.

/edit2: I edited the description in the wiki to be correct:

```
Identity orientation points it along the +X axis. scale.x is the arrow length, scale.y is the arrow width and scale.z is the arrow height.
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on 2014-05-19**:
What did you do? Just trial an error to get round arrows? Should we somehow file a bug report?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-05-19**:
See edit of original answer.

**Comment by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on 2014-05-20**:
Many thanks!!!